# Show number of pages views

Tags: views, theming, nodes

I am new to Drupal, so I want to know how do I echo number of views of a page ? or of a category ?

Comment: You're going to have to break this down a bit more I'm afraid!  It's a bit of a broad request :)

Answer (score 3):

If you go your modules admin screen (/admin/modules), you'll see there's a module called **Statistics** that actually comes with core Drupal.  Make sure you enable it on this screen if it isn't enabled already.

This will print out page views at the bottom of your pages, but you have to make sure you visit the permissions screen to give anonymous users (if that's what you're trying to do) the ability to see that.  After the module has been enabled, you'll see the following set of permissions for your site(/admin/people/permissions):

- Administer statistics
- View content access statistics
- View content hits

You'd just need to check the last one for whomever you want to be able to see the page views!

You can find additional information about this module on your own site's help pages: /admin/help/statistics

Comment: Sidenote: the Statistics module is a nightmare for performance, and should not be used on high-traffic sites.

Comment: What do you use for displaying page hits, Yuriy?  I use Google Analytics (the module), but that, of course, won't display the page hits on the page itself.  Let us know if you have alternatives...

Comment: There are some alternatives, but none which are quite as easy to use as the default Statistics module. You could use awstats to process Apache's logfiles, or store the visit data in a fast external system like memcache or redis and then write the numbers to Drupal's database during cron runs.